# Passing Parameters from An Activity to BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, parameters, android-activity, parameter-passing, broadcastreceiver

Hey I have been trying to pass an array of string from my activity to broadcast receiver but it always give me null at broadcast receive i have tried it in 2-3 ways.

```
// Code in Receiver
String stringText= intent.getExtras().getString("string_text");

//Code in Activity
   Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
i.putExtra("string_text", "abc");
 sendBroadcast(i);
```

but at receiver end stringText always come null. I have tried it in another way but no luck

```
String text= (String)intent.getSerializableExtra("string_text");
```

But till now no luck can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class GlobalVariable extends Application {

  private String[] var;

  public String[] getVar(){
    return var;
  }
  public void setVar(String[] var){
    this.var= var;
  }
}
```

And called it in my activity

```
GlobalVariable appState = ((GlobalVariable) this.activity.getApplication());
appState.getVar()
```

above line of code to retrieve similar way to set

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you trying to communicate from an activity to a broadcast receiver? That is extremely unusual behavior, to the point that it suggests a code organization problem.

Second, why are you using `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`? I am fairly confident that you do not work for Google. Hence, you should not be using a system-defined action string. In fact, it is quite possible that this is the source of your difficulty -- I doubt that you can send that broadcast.

Comment: I have done it by using a class that extends application and called my variables through application scope and now its working fine for me